# VB.Net Database Program (Console Application)

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am currently beginning my studies on this programming language and I have been wondering why parts of my program are not working correctly. The main problem I have came across is within the VIEW function, where when I try to view the records, only the most recent record added is shown and is shown several times. The other parts of the program I am unable to understand how I am going to tackle, this includes the UPDATE function and the DELETE function, where they update records or delete records of choice... Any guidance is appreciated (CODE SHOWN BELOW)

---

```
Module initialise Structure Record Public recFirstname As String Public recSurname As String Public recPhoneNum As String End Structure
    Public Contact As Record
    Public recLength As Integer = Len(Contact)
    Public numOfRecord As Integer

    Public firstName As String = Contact.recFirstname
    Public surName As String = Contact.recSurname
    Public telephone As String = Contact.recPhoneNum
    Public myFileName As String = CurDir() & "/myphonebook.dat"
    End Module

    Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String
        Do
            Do
                Console.WriteLine(" ************************************")

                Console.WriteLine(" If you want to VIEW existing files...")
                Console.WriteLine(" Press V, then hit enter" & vbNewLine)

                Console.WriteLine(" If you want to CREATE a new record...")
                Console.WriteLine(" Press C, then hit enter" & vbNewLine)

                Console.WriteLine(" If you want to UPDATE an existing record...")
                Console.WriteLine(" Press U, then hit enter" & vbNewLine)

                Console.WriteLine(" If you want to DELETE an existing record...")
                Console.WriteLine(" Press D, then hit enter" & vbNewLine)

                Console.WriteLine(" To QUIT: Press Q, then hit enter")

                Console.WriteLine(" ************************************")

                input = Console.ReadLine
                input = input.ToUpper

                If input <> "V" And input <> "C" And input <> "U" And input <> "D" And input <> "Q" Then
                    Console.WriteLine(" ---UNRECOGNISABLE BUTTON PRESSED.---" & vbNewLine & " ---PLEASE ENTER A VALID INPUT.---" & vbNewLine)
                End If

            Loop Until input = "V" Or input = "C" Or input = "U" Or input = "D" Or input = "Q"

            Select Case input
                Case "V" : procVIEWfile()
                Case "C" : procCREATEfile()
                Case "U" : procUPDATEfile()
                Case "D" : procDELETEfile()
                Case "Q" : End
            End Select

        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub procVIEWfile()
        Dim firstName As String = Contact.recFirstname
        Dim surname As String = Contact.recSurname
        Dim telephone As String = Contact.recPhoneNum
        Dim myFileName As String = CurDir() & "/myphonebook.dat"

        If numOfRecord < 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(" ---YOU DO NOT HAVE ANY RECORDS!---" & vbNewLine & " ---PLEASE ADD THEM BEFORE YOU TRY TO VIEW THEM.---" & vbNewLine)
        End If

        FileOpen(1, myFileName, OpenMode.Random, , , recLength)

        For i As Integer = 1 To numOfRecord
            FileGet(1, numOfRecord, i)

            Console.WriteLine(" *****************" & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Firstname: " & firstName & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Surname: " & surname & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Phonenumber: " & telephone & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" *****************" & vbNewLine)

            Console.WriteLine(" ---PRESS ANY KEY FOR THE NEXT FILE---" & vbNewLine)

            Console.ReadLine()
        Next

        FileClose(1)

        Main()

        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub procCREATEfile()
        Dim myFileName As String = CurDir() & "/myphonebook.dat"

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & " ---CREATING A FILE...---" & vbNewLine)

        FileOpen(1, myFileName, OpenMode.Random, , , recLength)
        numOfRecord = LOF(1) / recLength

        Console.WriteLine(" ***********************")

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & " Enter the Firstname")
        firstName = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & " Enter the Surname")
        surName = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & " Enter Phonenumber")
        telephone = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine(" ***********************")

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & " ---FILE CREATED---" & vbNewLine)

        numOfRecord += 1

        FilePut(1, Contact, numOfRecord)

        FileClose(1)

        Main()
    End Sub

    Private Sub procUPDATEfile()
        Console.WriteLine(" ---UPDATE FUNCTION ACTIVATED---")

        Dim answer As String
        For i As Integer = 1 To numOfRecord
            FileGet(1, Contact, i)
            Console.WriteLine(" *****************" & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Firstname: " & firstName & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Surname: " & surName & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Phonenumber: " & telephone & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" *****************" & vbNewLine)
            Console.WriteLine(" Is this the file you wish to update? Y/N" & vbNewLine)
            answer = Console.ReadLine()
        Next

        FileClose(1)

        Main()
    End Sub

    Private Sub procDELETEfile()
        Console.WriteLine(" ---DELETE FUNCTION ACTIVATED---")

        FileClose(1)

        Main()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Where does `numOfRecord` get set?

Comment: In the initialise module ^ "Public numOfRecord As Integer"

Comment: Because you never update the value of your variables (firstname, surname, telephone) inside the for loop, so you're simply repeating the values you assign in the `Dim` statements. You need to update the variables within the loop, and you've done nothing to do so.

Comment: Should the values not correspond to what number of record the For loop is on? ("For i As Integer = 1 To numOfRecord
        FileGet(1, numOfRecord, i")     Maybe this isn't what you mean? Sorry, I'm really just new to all this.

Comment: P.s - Sorry if I kill the braincells of others who read my comments, I hope you all can understand that I'm completely new to programming and is why I have decided to start with VB.Net.

Comment: I see nothing that populates any of the values of `Contact` except the `Dim` statements I mentioned before. Your call to `FileGet()` simply reads from the file and throws away the content it gets back. It never does anything to read any new values into the members of `Contact` from the file on each pass through the loop.

Comment: I have tried changing the FileGet() function so that it is inside the loop, adding +1 to the numOfRecord value everytime a record has been added so that when the view function is called, every record should be seen until there is no more records left but it's still not working... I'm stumped:/ Am I just being stupid? Haha

Comment: Also, I have looked throughout the depths of the internet and I'm unable to find any help to have the 'update' and 'delete' functions to work in the program. If I could get any guidance to how to do that, it would be very much appreciated.